# --capture-image-and-download is not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm building a macOS Application which is communicate with DSLR camera for capturing the image. For communicating with DSLR I am using **gPhoto2** library. And running all commands through my application. For capturing the

```
--capture-image-and-download --filename=/Users/xxxxx/Pictures/Foldername/filename.JPG.
```

and response

> New file is in location /capt0000.jpg on the camera
> Saving file as /Users/xxxxx/Pictures/Foldername/2020-07-19 18-48-58_image.JPG
>
> Deleting file /capt0000.jpg on the camera

This command working fine while running on the terminal and debug mode of my application. But When I archive my application for end-user then That .app file does not working properly like it gives the same response but gphoto2 is not downloading the image on the location in the machine.  I have provided full disk access permission.